# as3 filp bitmap both vertical and horizontal

Tags: actionscript-3

just a quick one i would like to flip the image both vertical and horizontal.

my code below is only doing me vertically anything not right?

```
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.scale(1,-1);
matrix.translate(0,bitmapData.height);

var flipHorizontalMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
flipHorizontalMatrix.scale(-1,1);
flipHorizontalMatrix.translate(bitmapData.width,0);

bitmapData.draw(loaderInfo.loader, matrix);


var image:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
image.width = 1024;
image.height = 702;
Bitmap(image).smoothing = true;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not try a simpler approach:

```
// Reverse the X and Y scale, flipping the image along both axis.
image.scaleX = image.scaleY = -1;
```

Comment: @bluebill1049 Yep, `image` refers to the same object in my answer as it does your question, so the Bitmap.

Comment: really wow that's so simple thanks Marty u always so helpful !!

Comment: quick question can you apply two Matrix to a bitmapData?

Comment: @bluebill1049 Should be able to, give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to Matrix, the following code works. Just tested :)

```
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.scale(1,-1);
matrix.scale(-1,1);
matrix.translate(0,bitmapData.height);
matrix.translate(bitmapData.width,0);

bitmapData.draw(loaderInfo.loader, matrix);


var image:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
image.width = 1024;
image.height = 702;
Bitmap(image).smoothing = true;
```